# Python Int32 to JSON

Tags: python, ros

I am not experienced in Python and getting confused by data types.

I'm receiving an Int32 type field from ROS (http://wiki.ros.org/msg) which I need to make to be part of a JSON, but the json.dumps fails due to the Int32 type:

> json.dumps(angle)
>   TypeError: data: 72 is not JSON serializable

Casting Int32 to integer fails too, for example when using:

> angle = int(angle or 0)
>   TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Int32'

Is there a way to change the type of a variable from a custom type to a standard one? I cannot change the source where I'm receiving it.

EDIT: Thanks to others pointing out, the error messages were actually telling "TypeError: data: 72 is not JSON serializable" - shows that this variable actually has the value of "data: 72", while due to my inexperience with Python I thought that the "data:" part of the error message was from the error and not from the variable. I guess it would be more obvious if it would be using quotes:

> TypeError: "data: 72" is not JSON serializable

Anyhow, this is obviously a rookie mistake. Apologies.

Comment: `print repr(angle)` and post what it says

Comment: How are you receiving it from ROS?

Comment: @JoranBeasley print repr(angle) gave "data: 72"

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm subscribing to a topic which is being published with an Int32 type message from the std_msgs.msg ROS package

Answer (score 1):

`Int32` is a class, the actual integer value is stored in a member named `data`. You can simply access it with:

```
angle.data
```

So in your case it should be:

```
json.dumps(angle.data)
```

---

A tip for the future: you can always look at the structure of a message type using `rosmsg show` on the terminal. For example

```
rosmsg show std_msgs/Int32
```

Has the following output:

> int32 data

So you can see, that the message `Int32` consists of one field with the name `data` that has the type `int32` (with small 'i' so this is really a integer).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to @Tui and @Joran pointing out that this message from ROS is in the format of "data: 72", so I turned it into a string and split it by the space and then turned the number part into a number:

> angle = str(angle).split(' ')
>   angle = int(angle[1])

Comment: ummm alright ... that doesnt seem like the right thing to do ... but im not familiar with the module so i dont really know

Comment: You are right, surely there is a nicer way to parse that integer into a python integer variable, but for now this will do (I'm no expert in Python and this is just a side-project)

Comment: from the docs In Python, the generated Python message file (e.g. std_msgs.msg.String) provides nearly all the information you might want about a .msg file. You can examine the `__slots__` and _slot_types and other fields to introspect information about messages. so maybe `print angle.__slots__`

Comment: its surely must have something like `angle.value`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Your almost right, it is `angle.data` :). See my answer.